# RESTful operations, server-side operations

Tags: rest, operations

Ok, I've got a Payment system.  Let's ignore everything around it, and focus on the Payment itself.

Through a bunch of wizards, I build up a particular payment.

First, I do a

> POST /payment

server returns

> LOCATION /payment/{id}

first Wizard page:

> PUT /payment/{id}

server returns

> 201 (Created)

Subsequent wizard page:

> PUT /payment/{id} and
>   POST /payment/{id}/{subresource}

server returns

> 202 (accepted) for the PUTs and 
>   201 (Created) for the subresources

Last page (has nothing but a summary and an "are you sure")

Here's my question, what should I use as the REST endpoint?

> PUT /payment/{id}/process

is plainly wrong, because process is a verb, not a resource.

> PUT /payment/{id}

implies the client is going to do the processing, which is something the server does not trust.

> PUT /payment/{id}

with the status changed (to something like "To Process") and having that status change be intercepted seems very hacky and not good design at all.

Anyone have other ideas?

Comment: I ended up using PUT /payment/{id} with a status Change.  Of all the solutions presented, it seemed the least abuse of transactional language and REST.  I'm still not happy with the solution...

Answer (score 2):

First do a GET of the payment:

```
GET /payment/{id}
```

Take that representation and POST it to a processing resource

```
POST /payment/processqueue
```

The Location header can contain a link to some resource that shows the status of the processing.

Comment: You could also use the term "PaymentProcessor" so you would send the payment with `POST /PaymentProcessor`.

Comment: I would protest that either the queue or the processor are not really resources, you're still posting to an operation.  Functionally, the implementation on the backend is just 1 method on the "PaymentService", there's no reason to create a "PaymentProcessor" object, when all the information and configuration is in the service.  So in other words, we're making phantom resources to serve as "resources" just to satisfy RESTfulness.  Is that worth the potential confusion?

Comment: I guess I don't really understand your definition of "resource". For me, a queue or a processor is a thing -- a noun -- and hence it is possible to make it a resource. In this case it is a container of or perhaps collection of payment resources or maybe payment resource URLs. I don't think it is "phantom" in any sense. I imagine having a URL that shows me a list of pending payments to be potentially useful. Help me understand the source of this potential confusion.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back here.  I didn't see that stackoverflow sent me an email...

Comment: I think the basic trouble I have is that this is a  a synchronized operation, not an async queue.  The user is supposed to immediately get feedback on whether the operation succeeded or not.  In the old style, you could be calling a Stateless EJB, or a Spring .do/.action.  It would do the work, and return.  In the new style, it would do the same thing.  The only difference is the naming.  We **DO** want to display/track payments, but there is no concept of a process queue.  To create one just to be RESTful seems overdone.